# Conditioning based on checkbox status

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

When a potential User is editing their Profile, they have an option to show/hide some information from public view. I did that with

```
<div class="field">
    <%= f.text_field :contact %>
    <%= f.select(:contact_type_id, ContactType.all.map {|l| [l.name, l.id]}) %>
    <%= f.check_box :visible %>
    <%= f.label :visible, "Vidljivo" %>

    <%= f.link_to_remove "Izbriši kontakt" %>
</div>
```

in a partial that's called in the view like this

```
<%= f.fields_for :contacts do |l| %>
    <%= render 'contacts_form', f: l %>
<% end %>
```

What I now want is to display on a public profile page only that information that the User marked as visible, and I tried it through a different partial

```
<div class="field">
    <% if :visible == true %>
        <%= f.text_field :contact %>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

called from

```
<%= f.fields_for :contacts do |l| %>
    <%= render 'contacts_show', f: l %>
<% end %>
```

but it doesn't work. I tried tons of variations, but it all came down to guessing the right syntax. How do I display only those entries which visibility is marked as "true"?

Answer (score 0):

Why are you displaying the public profile as a form? If you only want to show the information you can iterate over the contact information of the user where the contact type is visible.

Comment: I'm using nested_form_for(@user) so rails automatically collects only those DB entries that belong to the current user. I thought it was more practical than manually searching the database.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by using a different approach. In my user controller I defined an instance variable @visible and passed it the array consisting of all database entries that have visible parameter set to true. Then I used @visible.each in the view to print the desired content.